# How to log custom variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

I want to log the request duration. For that, I have a middleware and on the `OnActionExecuted` I assign the time elapsed to a variable and try to register it using the [Custom Layout Rendere through a lambda function](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer)

```cs
requestDuration = _stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
LayoutRenderer.Register("requestDuration", logEvent => requestDuration);
```

On my nlog.config I have the following

```
<column name ="RequestDuration" layout="${requestDuration}" quoting="Nothing"/>
```

NLog complains saying that this will be ignored:

```
Error Error parsing layout requestDuration will be ignored. Exception: System.ArgumentException: LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'requestDuration'
   at NLog.Config.Factory`2.CreateInstance(String itemName)
   at NLog.Layouts.LayoutParser.GetLayoutRenderer(ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory, String name)
```

Am I registering the layoutRenderer at the wrong place?

Please note that I'm trying to have a column that is the request duration, and not simply writing that time on the log message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get "LayoutRenderer cannot be found" while you have registered your layout renderer, then NLog parsed the config before the layout register.

You could do a [reinitialize](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Reinitialize-NLog-configuration) after the register:

```
LogManager.Configuration = LogManager.Configuration.Reload();
```

Although registering earlier is better.

Please note that it looks like a custom layout renderer for this case isn't really needed. There are a lot of context options for this, see https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context

Comment: Wouldn't this imply that whenever the app passes through the middleware, it would reload the config? Currently exploring the [LogEvent Properties Dictionary](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer#logevent-properties-dictionary)

Comment: It only reloads if you edit the config file (and have autoreload enabled) or explicit call. It won't reload automatically after registering a layout renderer

Comment: There is nothing bad with reloading the NLog config if you don't do it too many times (e.g every log message). Hope this answers your questions

Comment: In this case it would reload everytime it would enter on the middleware (I suppose). Either way, thanks to your link (I had read it before, but went there again), the MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext does exactly what I need. Thanks!